# how to stop a program in try/except

Tags: python

I want to stop my program when my try loop is respected

I tried putting the sys.exit () statement, but the program does not stop

```
def prints():
    with open ("{}.txt".format(name), "r") as printer :
    contain = printer.readlines()
    print(''.join(contain))

name = input("Enter the file name : ")
try:
    prints()
    sys.exit()
except:
    pass

<more code>
```

I was hoping that the program would stop after running the prints function, but currently the program continues after running the function

Comment: Indentation after of your `with open(...) as ...:` is still wrong

Comment: Make sure your program really enters `prints()` (f.e. 1st line inside function: `print("entering prints()")` and make sure it throws no exception (`print("exception")` instead of `pass` in the except: block,

Comment: @metmirr he is currently fixing indentation of posted code....

Comment: sys.exit() works by raising an exception - which you catch and discard! That is why it is a bad idea to catch exceptions unconditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare `except` catches `SystemExit` so the `sys.exit()` call is prevented from causing the program from exiting.

Move `sys.exit()` out of the try.

Also I don't like to see a bare `except` without a `logging.exception('')` in it.